# Voronoi diagram in a graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, cg.comp-geom

Let $G$ be a graph with (positively) weighted edges.
I want to define the Voronoi diagram for a set of nodes/sites $S$, to
associate with a
node $v \in S$
the subgraph $R(v)$ of $G$ induced by all the nodes
strictly closer to $v$ than to any other node
in $S$, measuring the length of a path by the sum of weights on the arcs.
$R(v)$ is $v$'s *Voronoi region*.
For example, the green nodes below are in $R(v_1)$, and the yellow nodes
are in $R(v_2)$.

          [image]
I would like to understand the structure of the Voronoi diagram.
As a start, what does the diagram of two sites $v_1$ and $v_2$ look like,
i.e., what does the 2-site *bisector* look like (blue in the above example)?
I think of the bisector $B(v_1,v_2)$ as the complement of $R(v_1) \cup R(v_2)$
in $G$.  Here are two specific questions:

> Q1. Is the bisector of two sites connected in some sense?
>
> Q2. Is $R(v)$ convex in the sense that it contains the shortest path between any two
>   nodes in $R(v)$?

Surely this has been studied before.  Can anyone provide references/pointers?
Thanks!

---

Addendum for Suresh's comment:

          [image]

Comment: Regarding Q2: Surely this should be no in general, because it's not true for Riemannian manifolds in general (cf the sphere). Might be interesting to ask what the discrete equivalent of the injectivity radius.

Comment: @Suresh: Could you expand your remark to indicate how one achieves nonconvexity on the sphere?

Comment: For Q1 to make sense you need some sense of faces, right? Otherwise, the "real" bisector is in the middle of edges, and introducing vertices just before and after this point, guarantees that the bisector is disconnected. Maybe if you assume the graph is chordal you can prove something. As for Q2: this is false even for geodesics in a polygon with holes (or terrains). My guess would be that you need to assume something quite strong on the graph to get non-trivial answer to both questions.

Comment: Thanks, Sariel, for those observations.  Yes, it appears I was hoping for too much, and perhaps only in special classes of graphs will there be nice structural properties.

Comment: ah so on the regular sphere a voronoi cell can't get bigger than a hemisphere, so you don't have this problem. But my comment more generally was the same as Sariel's in that you're asking for convexity of voronoi cells in a potentially generic riemannian manifold and that's shouldn't be true.

Comment: @Suresh: Yes, I see now, sorry for not catching your point immediately!

Comment: For Q1, a simpler counterexample is the bisector of $S$ where $S$ is the left side of $K_{2, n}$. The bisector is totally disconnected.

Comment: So now I am thinking maybe there is an interesting question here. What if the underlying metric is a manifold (as suggested by Suresh). Now, we connect two points if and only if there exists a third point q, such the other two points are the two nearest neighbors (think about this as some kind of witness complex). A natural conjecture would be that if the manifold is doubling, then one can always add O(1) points such that the bisector is connected. Hmmm...

Answer (score 8):

Mehlhorn, K.: A faster approximation algorithm for the Steiner problem in graphs.
Information Processing Letters 27, 125–128 (1988)

Erwig, M.: The graph Voronoi diagram with applications. Networks 36(3), 156–163
(2000)

both references copied from

Matthew T. Dickerson, Michael T. Goodrich, Thomas D. Dickerson, Ying Daisy Zhuo: Round-Trip Voronoi Diagrams and Doubling Density in Geographic Networks. Transactions on Computational Science 14: 211-238 (2011)

Comment: This will take some digging, but superficially, it does not seem that many structural properties of the diagram have been identified in these papers (perhaps because there are few properties of note!).

Comment: indeed not much seems to be known;
we have another lemma or two in http://www.sommer.jp/voronoi.htm